# Are there any features that ReactJS possess, while AngularJS lacks?

Tags: angularjs, reactjs

I was playing with ReactJS for a bit, and given a bit of prior exposure to AngularJS, and the way things are done in the latter, I had a hard time to get used to the syntax and the 'flow' of React.

So I had the above-mentioned question, plus: are there scenarios when ReactJS should be preferred to AngularJS?

Could anyone point out what can be done [easier/better/more efficiently] in React rather than in Angular, and other way around.

Answer (score 2):

It's actually the opposite.  Angular has a lot of features, apis, configuration options, etc.  React tries to be much simpler and let you choose how your application is structured.  Controllers, directives, and templates are reduced to just components.  Services are just plain JavaScript, there's nothing React specific about it.  Things like $q and $timeout don't exist because there's no digress (use anything you like for those).

You use React in your application, vs making your application *in* angular.

Answer (score 1):

ReactJS uses the concept of virtual DOM which speeds up the rendering of the app.

Watch Pete Hunt's excellent video on Virtual Dom here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-DX3vJiqxm4

The syntax might be very unconventional but the same thing can be said about Angular's concept of Directives, services, controllers, etc.  It just takes time to get used to, but once you feel comfortable, you'll find that thinking in ReactJS really makes sense.